# How to detect when an internet-browser is open in Windows Forms and do an action if an URL was fired?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a program which recognizes when a browser is open and which do every time an action, when the user went to a website. For example:

The program is running as a system tray and starting automatically on windows startup. (this works)

- Now the program runs an function, if the client open a random internet-browser (IE, Chrome, ...) which have the example-code `MessageBox.Show("You opened a browser!")`.
- If the user types for example "www.google.com" in the address bar and push [enter] the program should open an example-function like `MessageBox.Show("You entered " + enteredURL)` before the Website is loaded.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Only thing I could think of would be to try and look at the task manager and look for new processes (browsers) opening. In regards to traffic though... no idea

Comment: On looking at this again, I'm suspecting an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Navigating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event:

> Occurs before the WebBrowser control navigates to a new document.

It is possible to connect to an existing instance of IE, but you'll need to work with underlying the COM API ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

For other browsers *there is no general mechanism*: you'll need to work out if some API even exists browser by browser.

Comment: OP's not talking about an 'in app' web browser control... they are talking about a windows form app that integrates with existing browsers.

Comment: @PaulZahra for IE, even if connected to an external instance, it is the same event (the name and usage are different: [`BeforeNavigate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). For other browsers... I'll update